# Welcome email in Exchange 2003

Tags: exchange-2003

Is there a way to make Exchange 2003 send a "welcome" email to a user when their account/mailbox is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not with Exchange.  Clients (such as Outlook) will send this message as they are completing / testing their configuration.  Otherwise you'd have to send it manually or via script.

Comment: I agree, this sounds like a great scripting project.  Extra credit for creating the user account, mailbox, and welcome email all in the same script.